# Problem with pushing json to array and get it back to use it

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, charts, foreach

I'm getting my json from single run of CGI script and pushing it into array. In my case it is necessary to have a lot of jsons and then use them. So in my code, I get jsons and finnaly try to draw a chart. Simplier: I need an array of jsons.

I was trying to get the results from forEach nested function, but I had an error:

> Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

Here is code from HTTP Request to get json from CGI script and push it into array:

```
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var data= this.responseText;
    arrayOfData.push(data);
   }
```

Then I was trying to get first json by forEach and use to draw chart in D3.

```
var data = arrayOfData[0];

 data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.num = d.num;
        d.time_test = d.time_test;
   });
```

But then I have got an error: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefinded.
arrayOfData is global variable, so it is not a problem.
Maybe you know where is..

Thank you for help in advance

Comment: You need to parse your json to be able to loop through it (if it does have an array). use `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Seeing as the value is undefined, this is likely to be a async issue.

Comment: @jro it shouldn't be a async issue, because function draw is a callback function after HTTP Request

Comment: Well i mean it was due to code running asynchronously, such as the callback

Comment: Of course, @AvcS is right too.

Comment: @AvcS after JSON.parse(data) I have got a new error: Unexpected token u in JSON in position 0. I must add that this JSON worked directly from d3.json("cgi script", function, error) { data.forEach...}.

Comment: `Unexpected token u in JSON in position 0` error is coming because your variable `data` is `undefined`, first you need to make sure proper json is coming from ajax response and then parse it

Comment: A simple check to see this is indeed an async issue, just console.log inside the `onreadystatechange` and inside `draw` and see which one is getting logged first

Comment: Yes, you were right, thank you. I thought that callback function runs after HTTP Request, because I call it at end of function..

Comment: I solved this problem, but I have next.. "data.forEach is not a function". I don't know what's wrong..<br/>   var data = arrayOfData[0];
  JSON.parse(data);

 data.forEach(function(d) {
 console.log(d.time_test);
 console.log(d.num);
   });